# is there any option to prevent routing of href links to next page?

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-selectors

Is there any option to prevent routing of href links to next page, I want to display in index page with list?

```
</ul>
  <li><a href="elevationprofile.html">Elevation Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="bookmark.html">Bookmark Widget </a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to reload part of the page when a user clicks a link, rather than replacing the current page with the next one?

Comment: Try this in your tag `target="_self"`

Comment: Are you trying to show content from the link on the same page as the user? if so - you could create a modal that is shown on the link click and contains the content from the alternate page without leaving the index page. Also probably a typo - but you have a closing </ul> instead of an opening one <ul>

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this

```html
   <b>First</b>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Elevation Profile</a></li> //this method will take you to the top of the page on click
          <li><a href="#">Bookmark Widget </a></li>
        </ul>
   <b>Second</b>
   <ul>
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Elevation Profile</a></li> // this method will stays at the same scroll position on click
          <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Bookmark Widget </a></li>
          
        </ul>
```

Comment: Why would you want a menu where every item takes you to the top of the page? Or does nothing? The question *is* unclear, but I don't think this is what they're trying to ask for.

Comment: that's what i have thought but the OP wants to do this... So I answered